# how to initialize a char in a struct

Tags: c

I made a struct with three char:

```
typedef struct{
  char inside;
  char condition;
  char whattoprint;      
} array;
```

Then I make a 2d (array type) table and malloc it and all good by now

Then I want to call a function where I want to initialize my table and its like this:

```
array **initialize_table(int x,int y,array **table){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=x;i++){
       for(j=0;j<=y;j++){
          table[i][j].inside='.';
       }
    }
    return table;
}
```

the compiler doesn't show errors but when I run it there is segmentation fault in the "table[i][j].inside='.';" line and I don't know what I am doing wrong.
I hope you understand what I mean and if someone could help it would be great!

Comment: Use a debugger. Come back when you did.

Comment: What are you passing in as `table`? How is it created?

Comment: More than likely table was allocated incorrectly. Do you have that code?

Comment: You should probably show the code where you allocate the `array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
for(i=0;i<=x;i++){
    for(j=0;j<=y;j++){
```

In an array of length `x`, the indices go from `0` to `x-1`, so it should be

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
```

so that we don't access the nonexistant index `x`, and similarly for the inner loop:

```
for(j=0;j<y;j++){
```

Answer (score 2):

If the size of the is x y you should only be iterating up until x-1 y-1 i.e

```
int i,j;
for(i=0; i < x; i++){
   for(j=0; j < y; j++){
      table[i][j].inside='.';
   }
}
```